Theorem3.4 in Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry
I don't know the last part of proof.
I know $f$ is integral over $S(Y)$, and this means that there are elements $a_1,...,a_m \in S(Y)$ such that $f^m + a_1f^{m-1} + ... + a_m = 0$.
Since $f$ has degree$0$, we can replace the $a_i$ by their homogeneous components of degree$0$, and still have a valid equation.
I don't know this sentence. Why can we replace the $a_i$ by their homogeneous components of degree$0$ just because f has degree$0$.

Just look all degree 0 part of the equation. Original equation is defined in a graded ring.
